# What is the name of the following anti-pattern?

Tags: .net, inheritance, anti-patterns

As far as I know the following design is a known anti-pattern because the classes should be just instances of Person and not sub classes as they do not add anything to the base class:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person (string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class Karl : Person
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Karl";
        }
    }
}

public class John : Person
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "John";
        }
    }
}
```

Which is the name of this anti-pattern if any or how could I find more information about this topic?

EDIT: In the example the classes are exactly the same as :

```
Person karl = new Person ("Karl");
Person john = new Person ("John");
```

Why would I create new classes when instances are enough? The class does not add anything to the instance.

Comment: In some cases this is a valid design, in other cases it is not. Its not an automatic no-no

Comment: I don't exactly get the point; the classes `Opel` and `Renault` differ in behaviour, in contrast to the base class which is virtual and hence has no useful behaviour itself.

Comment: This is a good question but it appears to be off topic and probably belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: @Codor: Being `virtual` does not mean that there is no useful behaviour to itself, but I strongly suspect both you and the OP mean `abstract` there? In any case, I agree that the subclasses do add something to the base class, namely a specific behaviour for the `Name` property.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You are totally right, I mean abstract.

Comment: @pm100: I agree - in particular, there is no point in claiming that `Opel` and `Renault` "should be just instances" in the situation where each instance should later on represent a particular car of the respective make.

Comment: @ToAll: I added a explanation to the question and changed Car to Person as the point is probably clearer that way.

Comment: your new edit changes things completely. Renault is a class of car. Karl is an instance of person (I dont buy the idea that 'Karl' represents the class of people called Karl). This is for sure a no-no unless somebody has a very specific case in mind (modeling a specific college dorm with 3 well known people)

Comment: @SoMoS I'd say there isn't a direct known anti-pattern, but more of a possible code smell. The car version was better and might be perfectly fine in the long run, as you could in future have differences between car manufacturers. But the person example is pretty much a code smell.

Comment: If you are going to change it to person then do so in the entire question.  Exactly why would you create new classes when an instance will do.  It does not even rise to the level of anti-pattern to get a name.  And it has to compile to even be a pattern.

Comment: @Blam: thanks for your comment, it has been very valuable.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the `Name` change is the only change that is made in the sub classes in your real project.

Comment: You sub classes are breaking with Liskov substitution principle.